# mathpazo package and changing font within \begin{equation} ... \end{equation}

Tags: math-mode, fonts, equations, text-manipulation

I really like the mathapazo package but it changes all the text - NOT only the math environment. How I can edit the \usepackage{mathpazo} so that it effect only the math environment?! Does anyone has an idea?

Or please suggest some other nice fonts that I can make use within \begin{equation} ... \end{equation} the default is too ugly! I also don't know how to change a font within \begin{equation} ... \end{equation} - so, please give an example not just a line of code.

THANKS

Comment: It makes little sense to use a Palatino based math font with a different text font.

Comment: I said give an example! Short answer do not help either are appreciated.

Comment: It is easy to change the text font after you have loaded mathpazo. But if you want to see code: provide a minimal example that we can adapt and tell what font you actually want to use as text font. Short question without sensible informations aren't appreciated.

Comment: I am loading mathpazo but it changes the font everywhere, and I would like to change only the math environment. Example, well, I also said that \begin{equation} ... \end{equation}.. say \begin{equation} A+B+C \end{equation}. How to change the font only at the \begin{equation} ... \end{equation} part.

Comment: That is not a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that people can compile to illustrate your problem. All questions should include a complete, small compilable example, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also, you can edit your question. Code in comments is unreadable, does not help and is not appreciated either.

Comment: You can load a text font after `mathpazo` (or its successor, `newpxmath`). One of the few others I think looks good as a companion to Palatino math is Hermann Zapf’s other font Optima (available for TeX as the clone URW Classico).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just reset `\rmdefault` to the definition it had before `mathpazo` was loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\temp\rmdefault
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\let\rmdefault\temp

\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\[
\int_a^b f(x) dx
\]
\end{document}
```